# Vim copy to system clipboard using register not working (Mac computer)

Tags: macos, vim, clipboard

I have been spending some time looking for the solution. I have reinstalled Vim on my mac for several times using MacPorts. The vim --version command show that +clipboard and +xterm_clipboard, so I should be good to go. However, when I type "+yy or "*yy inside vim, the :reg command show that the register changed to the current line, but when I do paste outside vim, the content still did not change. Everything in vim I can tolerate to trade off its super flexibility, however, this copy/paste which is frequently used but extremely difficult in vim really driving me crazy...

Comment: Are you using the GUI or the TUI? If you use the TUI, do you use it within tmux?

Comment: I run vim directly from terminal window. Sorry about the confusion, I have modified my question. So it should be terminal vim not MacVim. And I do not use tmux

Comment: I tested MacVim GUI. The register seems to work. But I do like terminal vim, it is more flexible.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that if I add `set clipboard=unnamed` to my .vimrc, then  pasting outside of vim will paste the contents of the `*` register. For `+` you might try `set clipboard=unnamedplus`.

Comment: I tried, both. They do not work with me. As even direct register command do not even help.

Comment: By the way, I am running vim direct from command line. The MacVim GUI does work.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I am always using system vim, which is /opt/local/bin/vim. I think there was some glitch going on there. So I installed MacVim, and link vim to MacVim by adding the following code to my bash profile (~/.bash_profile)
**`alias vim='/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim'`**
Registers work perfectly with MacVim. Even though vim --version reveals that it is +clipboard but -xterm_clipboard.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I am using vim installed through Homebrew, and using `set clipboard=unnamed` is working for me, though not sure if the Homebrew version has anything to do with it. It is also +clipboard but -xterm_clipboard.

Comment: Ya. I tried both HomeBrew and MacPort before. It feels like that things are getting messy there.  Setting an alias is just a trick to get around, anyway, I am glad it does the job no matter what. `set clipboard=unamed` also do help.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a matter of updating the vim that ships with OS X (7.3) via homebrew to 7.4.